# grepping for exact variable from a file in shell

Tags: shell, grep

I have a file which contains multiple lines in an xml format. I am grepping for a variable/pattern in this file but having no luck with the exact match. The file example is

```
<ACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" useAdminAPI="false" manageDatagroups="false" publishDatagroups="false" ownDatagroups="false" groupname="Cyclops"/>
    <ACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" useAdminAPI="false" manageDatagroups="false" publishDatagroups="false" ownDatagroups="false" groupname="Cyclops Group"/>
   <ACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" useAdminAPI="false" manageDatagroups="false" publishDatagroups="false" ownDatagroups="false"  groupname="Viper"/>
 <ACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" useAdminAPI="false" manageDatagroups="false" publishDatagroups="false" ownDatagroups="false"  groupname="Wolf"/>
```

Now I want to get the line that has groupname as Cyclops. When I run `grep -w Cyclops`, i get both the lines. I tried `grep '\<Cyclops>\'` and still got the same result. I tried multiple other options mentioned in stackoverflow but nothing seems to work. Can you help me please?

The output I am expecting is

`ACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" useAdminAPI="false" manageDatagroups="false" publishDatagroups="false" ownDatagroups="false" groupname="Cyclops"/>`

when i grep the file for just Cyclops and

`<ACLEntry listACLEntries="false" modifyACLEntries="false" fullControl="false" useAdminAPI="false" manageDatagroups="false" publishDatagroups="false" ownDatagroups="false" groupname="Cyclops Group"/>`

when i grep for Cyclops Group.

Comment: if it's possible, pick an xml parser or using xpath to solve your problem. regex is not the recommended way of XML parsing

Comment: @Kent I understand, but this is just a simple grep right? does xml parsing affect who we grep in shell?

Comment: If you don't have other choices, or you are looking for a quick & dirty one-time solution, it's fine. Otherwise, applying regex on XML is risky, it has nothing to do with a simple or complex regex pattern.

Comment: for your example, you can try `grep 'groupname="Cyclops"'` but again it is not the right solution. Typical xpath problem.

Comment: Try single quoting the pattern like this `grep 'groupname="Cyclops"' ...`

Comment: Thanks @LeadingEdger and Kent. This worked. How would i do this if the Cyclops is variablized? Suppose i do `acl=Cyclops; grep 'groupname="$acl"' filename` doesn't work right? I tried `grep 'groupname=\"\$acl\"' filename` to escape the doublequotes and the dollar and it doesn't work.

Comment: A quick and dirty (not secure) way is `grep 'groupname="'$acl'"'  ...`